# WIFI not working after access point setup

Tags: raspbian, wifi, wireless, access-point

I have two RPi:s. I want one to act as an access point for the other one. Now I followed this tutorial on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S4E35d91Xss&t=188s . After all steps in the tutorial, I could access my RPi which I made as an access point from the other RPi (I could see the ssid name I chose for the access point). The problem is that the RPi I made as an access point now doesnt sense my wifi or any other wifi as it says "No wireless interfaces found". Any solution to this problem?

I tried:

sudo killall wpa_supplicant

sudo wpa_supplicant -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0

which took the wifi back to original setup and I could see the wifi:s but with the result that I couldnt access the RPi from my other one.

When connecting to my access point RPi from the other RPi it says:

wlan0: Associated with MyPie

wlan0: Configured 192.168.4.19/24

eth0: Link is down

Any suggestions?

Comment: let me get this straight, you want one pi to be an access point and a station at the same time using a single wifi interface?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. That was the plan but I understand now that it is impossible as it only either can act as AP or connected to wifi, not both. I also now understand that to be able to continue with my plan I need two wifi interfaces. In one acting as AP and in the other connected to WIFI. The third solution is routed AP but it isnt something for me.